# Gaming laptops that just work with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, touchpad

I recently purchased an [ASUS GL552VW](http://amzn.com/B01578ZKPO) laptop, and getting Ubuntu to work on it has been pretty awful so far -- the desktop installer didn't work so I had to use the server one, and then I manually installed packages like GPU drivers and `ubuntu-desktop`. At this point, I've spent over 10 hours of digging through forums, screwing with the BIOS, etc. getting this to work, and I still have suspend/resume errors and no touchpad support. I don't see any reason to expect things to get better from here; most stuff seems to be broken by default.

---

Complaining aside, how do I choose a computer that:

1. Is beefy -- I'm sure Ubuntu works just fine on a Thinkpad, but I want a modern gaming laptop.
2. Can dual boot alongside Windows 10 (the OS that will probably come with the laptop when I buy it)
3. Has a working GPU driver. I don't understand what a suspend/resume error is, and I truly don't care. I don't want to deal with drivers, beyond `apt-get install`-ing something.
4. "Just works", especially with regards to installation -- I don't want to spend another 10 hours on this. I want the desktop installer that I get from ubuntu.com to work; I don't want to put my programmer hat on just to get a computer to function.

I don't mind purchasing a older model if it means I can stop worrying about this stuff.

If Ubuntu isn't really there yet, that's a valid answer. I'll move on.

Thanks!

*P.S.*: I'm not necessarily asking for specific suggestions, but rather what heuristics I should look for when making my decision.

Comment: You can try [Ubuntu Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com). Also see: https://system76.com/laptops/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @muru: I didn't know about the Discourse. I'll ask there too. Though I think with the PS, this question becomes valuable to even strangers a year from now.

Comment: Not really, when the only answer is: buy from a vendor who supports Ubuntu. There's no other way to generally ensure you can dual boot or things just work. And which vendors support Ubuntu can change with time.

Comment: @muru: What vendors support Ubuntu today?

Comment: One I linked to in the first comment: System 76. More are listed here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you define a gaming laptop. Anyway: Dell has official support for Ubuntu for some product lines; drilling down to laptops with dedicated GPUs you can go to the the precision M3800 (or M4800 or M6800 if you need more powerful GPUs).

That said I don't see how the HW platform could interfere/relate to dual boot problems: any system will probably come with a preinstalled OS whether it's ubuntu or Windows and to have a seconde one you can resize partitions and install a second one (easier to have Windows 10 and then add Linux as grub will recognize the pre-existing Win installation) or just erase everything and install as you'd like.

Hope this can help.

Alessandro